# SQL Quarter Total and % increase top ten

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table where I need to create total sales by quarter of the product where the account_name and deal_id = X.

I then want a top 10 list of the largest % gainers from the previous quarter.

I have been doing this by creating a temp table, but the size of the table is about 1G and performance is not where we want it to be.  We can create another rollup table, but before I do that I would like to see if anyone has a suggestion on using this table first.

```
account_name    product_title   type    period  deal_id total_amount
Account1    product1    Type A  2002_Q4 9100    146.54
Account1    product1    Type B  2002_Q4 9100    34.32
Account1    product1    Type C  2002_Q4 9100    0.02
Account1    product2    Type A  2002_Q4 9100    14.45
Account1    product2    Type B  2002_Q4 9100    3.58
Account1    product1    Type A  2002_Q3 9100    68.23
Account1    product1    Type B  2002_Q3 9100    12.56
Account1    product1    Type C  2002_Q3 9100    75.21
Account1    product2    Type A  2002_Q3 9100    5.68
Account1    product2    Type B  2002_Q3 9100    3.2

product1    180.88  2002_Q4 16%     
product2    18.03   2002_Q4 103%        
product1    156     2002_Q3         
product2    8.88    2002_Q3
```

Ok, I added new data and included what the results would look like with the increase listed over the previous quarter.

Comment: What is `X` exactly?

Comment: Sorry about that.  X meant account_name = Account1 and deal_id = 9100.  I was just using X as those are variables that would be passed in the where clause.

Comment: The total amount per quarter would be the sum of the product1 totals that comprises its different types.  Type A + Type B + Type C = total. (46.54+34.32+.02=80.88 for Account1, product1, 9100, 2002_Q4)

Comment: I think I have a start on this. Now what do you mean when you say you want the larger % gainers? % of what?

Comment: % increase or decrease of products over the last quarter.  Example.  product1 increase 38%, product2 increased 29%.  Once we have the % increases we would want to list the top 10 % increased products and the top 10 % decreased products from the last quarter.

Comment: Using your example table, how do you arrive at those numbers? I'm seeing the same `total_amount` for both Q3 and Q4.

Comment: Do you only need the diff between the last two quartals?

Comment: @PaulSpiegel That's what I would guess, but if you look the total for `product1` in `2002_Q4` is the same as it is in `2002_Q3`. I believe this is just a misrepresentation of the data.

Comment: @TheDetective I think it's just a lazy c&p :-)

Comment: @PaulSpiegel Probably.

Comment: Yes, lazy c&p.  Sorry about that.

Comment: I can add some more real data if you like.

Comment: Just a little bit. About the same amount you have now.

Comment: Added more data

Comment: [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7a8ce/1) for future use.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way with fixed quartals:

```
select d.product_title, ((
        select sum(d1.total_amount)
        from deals d1
        where d1.account_name = 'Account1'
          and d1.deal_id = d.deal_id
          and d1.product_title = d.product_title
          and d1.period  = '2002_Q4'
    ) - sum(d.total_amount)) / sum(d.total_amount) * 100
    as diff
from deals d
where d.account_name = 'Account1'
  and d.deal_id = 9100
  and d.period = '2002_Q3'
group by d.product_title
order by diff desc
limit 10
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/65bd95/26

Here is another one - joining two subqueries:

```
select
  q3.product_title, 
  100 * (q4.total - q3.total) / q3.total as diff
from (
  select d.product_title, sum(d.total_amount) as total
  from deals d
  where d.account_name = 'Account1'
    and d.deal_id = 9100
    and d.period = '2002_Q3'
  group by d.product_title
) q3
join  (
  select d.product_title, sum(d.total_amount) as total
  from deals d
  where d.account_name = 'Account1'
    and d.deal_id = 9100
    and d.period = '2002_Q4'
  group by d.product_title
) q4 using (product_title)
order by diff desc
limit 10
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/65bd95/9

A helpfull index would be `(account_name, period, deal_id, product_title, total_amount)`. The first three columns can be in any order. The last one is optional, but makes it to a "covering" index.

Comment: Good work. I don't see how this could be dynamic e.g. getting `2002_Q2`, `2002_Q3`, and `2002_Q4` results without some messy regex. I think this will be the best option for OP.

Comment: This worked.  From a performance perspective the first one without the joins was exponentially faster. 9 sec compared to over a minute where I just killed the query.  That was after I put the correct indexes on the tables.  Thanks!!

Comment: @SeanPeace Just fixed missing `d1.account_name = 'Account1'` in the first subquery. Also check if you really have "the correct" index.

Comment: Thanks, yes, the query wouldn't work fast until I put the index on account_name, deal_id, period, and product_title.